# Работа программы прекращается

Tags: c

```
char Kid1 = "Robin";


printf("%s\n", Kid1);
```

Пример нашел в книге. Так можно объявлять символьный массив без квадратных скобочек? 
Потому что работа программы прекращается.

Comment: В какой книге? Вероятно, это опечатка.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь https://prog-cpp.ru/c-string/ char  либо массив либо константа поэтому  юзай  const char* если хочешь  хранить как стоковую константу

Comment: Такой код -  некомпилируем в принципе. О чём вам компилятор ясно сказал. Вы просто проигнорировали его сообщения?

Comment: Компилятор ничего не говорит. При запуске открывается терминальное окно.  Потом открывается окно Windows о прекращении работы этой программы. В книге был такой пример.

Comment: Книга Грег Перри Дин Миллер Программирование на С для начинающих.

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. Компилятор ясно указал вам на ошибку в этом коде. Диагностические сообщения компилятора нужно анализировать при компиляции, а не "при запуске".

Comment: Да вы правы там написано. Только не в терминале а в Build message.
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Comment: Именно об этом я и говорю. Код грубо ошибочен.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть, было написано так?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char* Kid1 = "Robin";
  printf("%s\n", Kid1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/415555)

Comment: @ИмяФамилия это ответ на вопроc, очевидно,  что из оригинального кода была упущена *

Comment: С пояснением всё хорошо.